# WD Elements Bought 2 weeks ago : clicking noise on only Some devices

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I bought the 1TB WD Elements USB3 external hard drive 2 weeks ago,

and i have some weird issues with it when i tried on:

- windows 7 >> worked - Read & write
- linux mint 15 >> Not recognized. although it was spinning up normal, and after so much trying, it did work when i connected the drive while the linux is booting up (My friend have the exact same model and actually was bought also 2 weeks ago, he tried it for the first time on Mint and it worked with no hassle after the first trial)
- Samsung galaxy tab 3 (with custom rom) >> Not recognized with clicking sound (no enough power) While my friend's drive is fully spinning and mounted
- Toshiba regza 32 inch TV with usb port >> Clicking sound

So, Should I replace this drive? or It is just bad coincidence of collective software problems not related to the hard drive at all?

What is the best thing to do right now?

Comment: Return the hard drive.

Comment: @karel : Why do you think that?

Comment: That's a good question. I am a loyal WD customer. So far I have never had any problems with a WD drive and none of my WD drives has ever failed, but if I ever did have any problems with a WD drive that was still under warranty I would return it immediately for a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run an extended test using Data Lifeguard Diagnostics to see if there will be any bad sectors or errors detected and tell me what the results were? Just make a backup of your data before doing so because if the program finds anything on the drive it will try to fix them automatically. You can download it from here:

http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=iKUkFC

Let me know how it went. :)

Comment: The device passed the test.What's next?

Comment: It's good that the drive passed the test, but it's the clicking noise that bothers me. That's why I would recommend to contact our support and see if they could help you further or to arrange a RMA if possible: http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=D7HsXk. Best of luck! :)